# floating point calculations in awk

Tags: awk, floating-point

I am surprised with behaviour of `awk` while performing **floating point** calculations. It lead me to wrong calculation on table data.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 2.3/0.1}'
23  <-- Ok
$ awk 'BEGIN {print int(2.3/0.1)}'
22  <-- Wrong!

$ awk 'BEGIN {print 2.3-2.2==0.1}'
0   <-- Surprise!
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 2.3-2.2>0.1}'  <-- Din't produce any output :(
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 2.3-2.2<0.1}'
1   <-- Totally confused now ...
```

Can somebody throw light as to what's happing here?

**EDIT 1**

As pointed by *@fedorqui*, output of second last command goes to file named **0.1** because of redirection operator (**>**).

Then how am I supposed to perform *greater than* (**>**) operation?

Solution to it is also given by *@fedorqui*

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print (2.3-2.2>0.1)}'
0  <-- Wrong!
```

Comment: +1 for interesting question. I found some info --> http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Issues.html Note also that `awk 'BEGIN {print 2.3-2.2>0.1}'` writes the result of `2.3-2.2` in a file with `0.1` name.

Comment: @fedorqui I also searched on this topic. All they say is expect unexpected behaviour! How am I supposed to solve my problem accurately? I tried solving in `perl` but unfortunately it also misbehaves, may be in different way.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks for pointing that out. I have updated question with addition query!

Comment: For this I guess the solution is to do `awk 'BEGIN {print (2.3-2.2>0.1)}'`. For the rest, I am still checking, it is a juicy topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following section from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Floating-Point-Issues) should help you understand the *issue* you're observing:

> **15.1.1.2 Floating Point Numbers Are Not Abstract Numbers**
>
> Unlike numbers in the abstract sense (such as what you studied in high
>   school or college arithmetic), numbers stored in computers are limited
>   in certain ways. They cannot represent an infinite number of digits,
>   nor can they always represent things exactly. In particular,
>   floating-point numbers cannot always represent values exactly. Here is
>   an example:
>
> ```
>  $ awk '{ printf("%010d\n", $1 * 100) }'
>  515.79
>  -| 0000051579
>  515.80
>  -| 0000051579
>  515.81
>  -| 0000051580
>  515.82
>  -| 0000051582
>  Ctrl-d
> ```
>
> This shows that some values can be represented exactly, whereas others
>   are only approximated. This is not a “bug” in awk, but simply an
>   artifact of how computers represent numbers.

---

A highly recommended reading:

[**`What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic`**](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103163)

Comment: No desire to spend $15

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html