# printf rounding in awk

Tags: linux, awk, printf

```
echo 2 9|awk '{printf("%.0f\n",$2/$1)}'
4
```

Result is 4;

but,

```
echo 2 3|awk '{printf("%.0f\n",$2/$1)}'
2
```

Result is 2.

Why? Who can tell me?

Comment: About floating point numbers: http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/fp/

Comment: Yep, this is consistently weird. From a shell prompt, `printf '%.0f\n' 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5`

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks!  Very informative!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not Abstract numbers and cannot always represent values exactly.

The answer to this question "[floating point calculations in awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656446/floating-point-calculations-in-awk)" has a good explanation of the problem.